# Unable to run app on Android device (Linux/Ubuntu)

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

The app runs with Ubuntu using android studio, it also runs using react-native on my windows 10.

A new app created with react-native init runs fine with ubuntu

but react-native run-android on my current app always returns this:

```
    Running /home/lance/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/

    adb -s 4d00550ff22a318d reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

    adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...

    * daemon started successfully *

    Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
    Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

    Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
    set up your Android development environment:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

    (node:5781) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
    Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): 
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

    (node:5781) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. 

    In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
    terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

- react-native 0.40
- Ubuntu 16.10 X64
- Samsung S4 (Android 5.0)

Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: does `adb devices` show your device as properly connected? have you tried installing the apk through `adb install`?

Comment: Yes, sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: Also there is a space missing in `adb -s 4d00550ff22a318dreverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, although I suppose that in console you are putting it right... you might try cleaning the project `cd android && ./gradlew clean` and then build again. In any case, from the console output you posted, I cannot see any helpful error message, so no more ideas.

Comment: yes it is right in console. It says ./gradlew: command not found. However I can clean through android studio but does not change the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by adding execution permission to gradelew.

In terminal, in react-native project folder, run

`chmod +x android/gradlew`